What's the total noise in this system?
The following is a revision (since I change the original question a little bit) from the book RF MICROELECTRONICS Page 47.
Calculate total noise of the common-gate stage depicted in Fig. 2.46(a).
Only assume \$I_1\$ current source is ideal.

The following are what I have tried. please point out any problems that may involve in my calculation.

$$\frac {V_{out}} {r_{o1}}= 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \overline{V_{n,R_1}^2} = 0$$

$$\frac {V_{out}} {r_{o1}} + I_n = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \overline{V_{n,M_1}^2} = I_n^2 r_{o1}^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \overline{V_{n,M_1}^2} = (4 K T \gamma g_{m1})^2 r_{o1}^2$$
So in total,
$$\overline{V_{n,total}^2}=  \overline{V_{n,R_1}^2} +  \overline{V_{n,M_1}^2} $$
$$\Rightarrow \overline{V_{n,total}^2}= (4 K T \gamma g_{m1})^2 r_{o1}^2$$

Hi! You're churning out new questions faster than you accept answers to your existing questions!
